# Excel: How to get Developer Form Control Reference Name Manager Value instead of Cell Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a drop-down box that only allows the user to select from a list of dates in another table. I created a reference in the Name manager that only pulls the unique date once, but when I try to use the reference as the Input Range on the format control it throws an error saying the reference isn't valid.

I've tried using indirect as well and that doesn't seem to work either.

Is it possible to use a reference on the input range of a drop-down tool in Excel?

Here are some screenshots of my issue.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIFEG.jpg)
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHimn.jpg)

Comment: would slicers work for you?

Comment: I'm only familiar with slicers on the pivot table level. That was my initial thought, but I'm new to pivot tables, and getting the slicer to easily let me select the month, day, and year was troublesome. If I had a good resource that would be helpful, but the slicer only seems to break down by month and year for me and overall feels very unfriendly from a UI perspective from what I know.